# PHPUnit Mock does not filter or ignores calls

Tags: php, unit-testing, magento, phpunit

I got a factory so this mock method is called "getModelMock".
It rewrites the setData method when the first argument is "template_text" to another function "fetchArgs" that stores the given arguments.

```
$coreEmailTemplateMock = $this->getModelMock(
    'core/email_template',
    array('setData')
);
$coreEmailTemplateMock
    ->expects($this->any())
    ->method('setData')
    ->with($this->equalTo('template_text'))
    ->will($this->returnCallback(array($this, 'fetchArgs')));
```

$this->replaceByMock('model', 'core/email_template', $coreEmailTemplateMock);

The method "setData" will be called at some time like `setData('template_text', 'foo')`. I know that because without the "with" clause I can see every argument that has been put in that function.

So to my understanding the first argument IS "template_text" at some time and I should see the "foo" too.

Without the `with()` I see every argument that has ever been parsed (my `fetchArgs` does that).

With the `with()` I see nothing.

What went wrong here? Something wrong with the `with()` I used?

thanks in advance!
cheers